# financeapi.net unavailable due to Server Error 403

Tags: python, api, finance

I am unable to call financeapi.net from any python script. It stopped working on the 25th of October 2022. It seems to be a problem on the server side (403).
It is strange to me that I can successfully execute calls on their specifications page with the same credentials, but not via any python script.

Given that financeapi.net does not have a support option, I was wondering if anyone would know how to fix it.

```
url = "https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/quote"

querystring = {"symbols":"ES=F"}
                
headers = {'x-api-key': apikey}

response1 = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
print(response1) # Returns "Response [403]"
future=response1.json()["quoteResponse"]["result"][0]
```

Tried to:

run the api call on the specifications page -> which worked.

pass additional specifications to the request function -> no impact

add 'accept': 'application/json' to the header -> no impact

use requests.get() -> no impact

fully specify the URL with all parameters i.e.

```
'https://yfapi.net/v6/finance/quote?symbols=ES%3DF'
```

-> no impact

unable reproduce the result in my browser

Answer (score 0):

Add "User-Agent" to the headers. I was having the same problem and this worked. I got this by email from support@financeapi.net.

headers = {
'x-api-key': "YOUR-PERSONAL-API-KEY",
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}